# Problem with Apex HTTP callout POST Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, httprequest, httpcalloutmock

I get the following error: "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" when executing my test. The code coverage is already at 88% but the error persist. This is my code:

The Apex Class:

```
public class PostOportunidades {

    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Llamada nuevo oportunidad')
    public static void LlamarInsertOpp(List<Opportunity> oportunidad) {
        if(oportunidad.size() > 0){
            Id idopp = oportunidad.get(0).Id;
           
            postOpp(idopp);   
        }
    }
    
    @future (callout =true)
    public static void PostOpp(ID idOportunidad){
        
        List<Opportunity>opps = [SELECT CloseDate,Fecha_Pago_de_Reserva__c,Monto_de_Reserva__c, AccountId,OwnerId, Banco__c, Description,Amount,Facturado_Con__c from Opportunity where ID= :idOportunidad];
       
         Opportunity opp = opps.get(0);
        list<Account> cuenta = [SELECT Identificacion__c from Account where ID = :opps.get(0).AccountId];
         
        if(cuenta.size() > 0 && opps.size()>0) {
           list<OpportunityLineItem> carro = [SELECT ProductCode from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId = :opps.get(0).Id]; 
           
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('The enda point. Can't put it here sorry ');
            request.setMethod('POST'); 
            if(carro.size()> 0){
                 request.setBody('fecha='+opp.Fecha_Pago_de_Reserva__c+'&cliente=' +cuenta.get(0).Identificacion__c +'&codigo_auto='+ carro.get(0).ProductCode +'&valor_venta='+ opp.Amount +'&fecha_cierre='+ opp.CloseDate +'&vendedor='+opp.OwnerId +'&deposito='+opp.Monto_de_Reserva__c + '&cheque=&num_cheque=&banco='+opp.Banco__c +'&cuenta=&observaciones='+opp.Description +'&deposito_inicial=&activa=1&empresa='+opp.Facturado_Con__c+'&idreservacion_cn=&usuario_actual=');
            }
          
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            //Respuesta del servidor
            if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {  
                System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                             response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            } else {
                System.debug(response.getBody());
            }
        }
        else{
            System.debug('Hay pe2');
        }
     

    }

    
}
```

Tests:
Mock:

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpReserva implements HttpCalloutMock {
      global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
      
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        res.setBody('fecha=2020-11-09&cliente=Prueba&codigo_auto=98&valor_venta=77&fecha_cierre=&vendedor=2&deposito=85&cheque=&num_cheque=&banco=&cuenta=&observaciones=&deposito_inicial=&activa=&empresa=&idreservacion_cn=&usuario_actual=');
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

Calling the mock:

```
@isTest
public class PostResrvaTest {
   @istest
   public static void PostReservaTestMethod (){
       
        List<Opportunity>ListaOp = new List<Opportunity>();
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name ='Prueba';
        acc.Identificacion__c = '1549878484P';
        insert acc;
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.Name = 'Prueba';
        opp.StageName = 'Reserva';
        opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
        opp.CloseDate = date.parse('24/09/2020');
       
        insert opp;
        ListaOp.add(opp);
       
        Test.startTest();
        
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpReserva());
            PostOportunidades.LlamarInsertOpp(ListaOp);
            //PostOportunidades.PostOpp(opp.Id);
            
         
        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Please help I'm still a noob

[image]

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with the code snippets you have posted. I was able to use them in my dev org (after removing the custom fields from the code) and test run was successful. Have you checked if there is any dependent functionality (such as trigger, flow etc.) that is getting invoked and causing disallowed sequence of operations? I bet one of these other code is causing DML or giving unexpected output. Check this out too: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328873&type=1&mode=1

Comment: I have no other triggers or flows that get called after any insert or update in the objects used here..